# Update fields at different levels in a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I'm trying to update different values ​​at different levels in a document in the database.

The code snippet I am using is the following:

```
     async actualizarTiempos(registroEventos): Promise<any> {
        console.log(registroEventos);
        const response = await registroEventos.eventos.map(async (evento) => {
          const query = {
            ficha: evento.ficha.ficha,
          };
    
          const update = {
            $inc: {
              acumulado: evento.horas,
              'competencias.$[comp].acumulado': evento.horas,
              'competencias.$[comp].resultados.$[resu].acumulado': evento.horas,
            },
          };
    
          const arrayFilters = [
            {
              'comp.codigo': evento.competencia.codigo,
              'resu.orden': evento.resultado.orden,
            },
          ];
    
          const registro = await this.gestorTModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, {
            arrayFilters,
          });
    
          return {
            registro,
          };
        });
```

But when I try to run the code it gives me the following error:

```
/home/juliandavidrealesdelaossa/Development/dds-backend/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:413
        callback(new MongoServerError(document));
                 ^
MongoServerError: Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'comp' and 'resu'
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/juliandavidrealesdelaossa/Development/dds-backend/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:413:18)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/juliandavidrealesdelaossa/Development/dds-backend/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:243:56)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/juliandavidrealesdelaossa/Development/dds-backend/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:187:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/juliandavidrealesdelaossa/Development/dds-backend/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:68:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
```